# jquery prevent redirect until after animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

This code works perfectly except when you click on a link, The page is redirected before jquery has a change to visually animate the margin back to zero. Is there a way to prevent the redirect until after jquery animates the margin back to zero?

HTML

```
 <div id="sidebar">
  <div class="navigation">
  <ul>
    <a href="../../../index.html"><li><img src="dbs/images/home.png" title="" width="40" height="38" />به عقب</li></a>
    <a href="../../000_Movies/_assets/playlist.html"><li>فیلم ها</li></a>
    <a href="../../020_IAM/_assets/playlist.html"><li>وزارتخانه ها ایران زنده</li></a>
    <a href="../../080_Worship/_assets/playlist.html"><li>پرستش</li></a>
    <a href="../../330_Teen/_assets/playlist.html"><li>جوانان</li></a>
    <a href="../../300_Children/_assets/playlist.html"><li>کودکان</li></a>
    <a href="../../400_Testimony/_assets/playlist.html"><li>پزوهش ها</li></a>
    <a href="../../600_SOC/_assets/playlist.html"><li>دانشکده مسیح</li></a>
    <a href="../../750_Women/_assets/playlist.html"><li>زنان</li></a>
    <a href="../../800_BAHAM/_assets/playlist.html"><li>کلیپ های سری</li></a>

  </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('.navigation a li').click(function () {
    $('.slider').animate({
        marginLeft: 0
    }, 500);
});
```

Comment: It makes me wonder what use case you have though. If you're going to be leaving the page, would it really matter so much for the animation to finish *before* you redirect? As a user, I'd say that that has a huge potential to irritate.

Comment: Im just trying some things out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

.animate() takes a callback function like so:

```
$('.navigation a li').click(function () {
    $('.slider').animate({
        marginLeft: 0
    }, 500,function() {
      //thing to do when you animation is finished e.g.
      location.href = 'http://redirect.to.url';
    });
});
```

For complete documentation, check out the (extremely useful) jQuery docs:
http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your HTML is invalid. Put the links inside the list items, not the other way around. Adjust your selector accordingly (`.navigation li a`).

Next, now that you're setting the event on the link rather than the list item, make your handler:

- Prevent the default event
- Add a callback to the animation, so that when the animation is over the page goes to `this.getAttribute('href')`.

That should do it.

Comment: How would I write the js for this

Comment: See Adam's answer for how to include the callback.

Answer (score 0):

Stop the event propagation from `li` click handler.

```
$('.navigation a li').click(function (e) {
    $('.slider').animate({
        marginLeft: 0
    }, 500);

    e.stopPropagation();
});
```